# Convert HTACCESS mod_rewrite directives to nginx format?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm brand new to nginx and I am trying to convert the app I wrote over from Apache as I need the ability to serve a lot of clients at once without a lot of overhead!

I'm getting the hang of setting up nginx and FPM/FastCGI PHP but I can't wrap my head around nginx's rewrite format just yet. I know you have to write some simple script that goes in the server {} block in the nginx config but I'm not yet familiar with the syntax.

Could anyone with experience with both Apache and nginx help me convert this to nginx format? Thanks in advance!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^school\.dev$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.school.dev/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the nginx conversion for your htaccess.

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
if ($http_host ~* "^school\.dev$"){
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.school.dev/$1 redirect;
}
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$query_string break;
}
}
```